GeoServerHomePage.selectionMode - where to configure?
in https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/config.html it states that there is a selectionMode property that can be configured.
my (stupid) question is: where do I configure said property? is it a context param? an application property? something else?
I couldn't find a reference in https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/index.html either.

I presume its an environment variable if it isn't set on the global settings page

On Windows editing the startup.bat file seems to work. I added -DGeoServerHomePage.selectionMode=text into this section:
:run
  cd "%GEOSERVER_HOME%"
  echo Please wait while loading GeoServer...
  echo.
  "%RUN_JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="%GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%" -Djava.awt.headless=true -DGeoServerHomePage.selectionMode=text -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -jar start.jar
  cd bin
goto end

I guess that the option can be added in the same way to last line of the  Linux shell file startup.sh. I do not know what to do when GeoServer is started as a service instead of using the startup scripts.

thank you, your answer works, although in the end I did try the context-param and it worked as well.

This is another way to set the selectionMode property that works as well.
add this in web.xml:
<context-param>
        <param-name>GeoServerHomePage.selectionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>text</param-value>
</context-param>

